# Alternate row coloring in ssrs 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, conditional-formatting

how can I add alternate row coloring where two rows in bunch should display one color and next two rows should display other color.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the BackgroundColor property of the table row to:

```
=IIF(Floor((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/2) Mod 2 = 0, "White", "Yellow")
```